# How to create a new service in MEAN stack framework?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a service named `user.service.js` which is used for getting the users data from the `users` collection. The same way I need a service called `courses.service.js` which is going to read all the data from the `courses` collection. Can someone please show me how to do that?

Comment: how about use your own `user.service.js` to get start? This is not a SO question.

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried.

Comment: Hi Mulkul Varshney
I am just following the below sample https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-stack-registration-login-example
 in that i am trying to add another service to get the datas from the "courses" collection

Answer (score 0):

Just add your module name and save file , change api url if needed

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  // Users service used for communicating with the plants REST endpoint
  angular
  //.module('coursesServices.admin.services')
  .factory('coursesService', coursesService);

  coursesService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function coursesService($resource) {

    var courses = $resource('/api/courses/:courseId', {
      plantId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });



    return courses;
  }

}());
```